# C# how to include 0 in Roulette Simulation?

Tags: c#, simulation, roulette-wheel-selection

So I want to simulate a roulette to proof that the House always wins.

I’m almost done but I stumbled upon a problem. I’m able to enter how many times to roll and it works fine. I get different numbers and it also tells me if red or black.

However the number 0 won’t show up in the results. I don’t know how to fix this, the code looks fine to me.

Code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] Null = new int[1] { 0 };
            int[] Rote = new int[18] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 30, 32, 34, 36 };
            int[] Schwarze = new int[18] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 29, 31, 33, 35 };

        // 0 ohne Tischlimit

        var list = new List<int>();
        list.AddRange(Rote);
        list.AddRange(Schwarze);
        list.AddRange(Null);

        Console.WriteLine("Wie oft soll gespielt werden?");
        int Anzahl = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Random zufall = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < Anzahl; ++i)
        {
            int number = list[zufall.Next(0, list.Count - 1)];

            if (Rote.Contains(number))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Rot" + number);
            }

            if (Schwarze.Contains(number))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Schwarz" + number);
            }

            if (Null.Contains(number))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Null" + number);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: `the House always wins` - well, if you keep playing it will, but if you are ever lucky enough to get ahead, you can always get up and leave :) Anyway, IMO, your next task should be to rewrite this program to give the exact same type of output but without the three arrays - they are not necessary for what you are doing here.

Comment: People are greedy,so its hard to just give up once you win a decent amount of money ^.^ can you give me a little hint?A friend recommended me to do it with arrays.

Comment: Indeed - that's how casinos stay in business :) -- Sure - you are interested in getting one of the outcomes red, black, or zero with the same probability as a roulette wheel. Those probabilities are 18, 18, and one, respectively, like your array dimensions. So you could just do (in shorthand) `r = random(37); if (r == 0) "zero" else if (r <= 18) "Red" else "Black"` (37 = 18 + 18 + 1, of course).

Comment: The problem with if (r <= 18) is,that also black numbers are < than 18

Comment: You're confusing the actual numbers on the roulette wheel with the probabilities of black and red. You don't need to simulate the actual number that would come out, just the probability of the color. Think of my logic as using a slightly non-standard roulette wheel where 1 through 18 is red and 19 through 36 is black.

Comment: Ohh man,thank you!Now i know i should better go to sleep lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the thing is that `Random.Next Method (Int32, Int32)` uses upper bound as exclusive. So you have `0` as last element of list. And passing `list.Count - 1` results in generating values between `0` and `list.Count - 2`. So the last element of the list is just ignored as you will never generate the last index `list.Count - 1`. You need to pass `list.Count` to `Next` method:

```
int number = list[zufall.Next(0, list.Count)];
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx

> The Next(Int32, Int32) overload returns random integers that range
>   from minValue to maxValue – 1

Comment: Thanks alot friend!Im still in the process of learning - can you maybe qoute for me how you would do it?I don´t really understand how you mean that.

Comment: Works like a charm now.Thank you!